# MySQL - return single record by joining multiple tables with multiple WHERE/OR clauses

Tags: mysql, left-join, inner-join

Did many searches and were able to write all the JOIN queries except this one. I have 3 tables, which look like:

```
TABLE - accounts
account_id | account_email
1          | aa@bb.com
2          | cc@dd.com

TABLE - products
product_id | product_name
1          | name1
2          | name2

TABLE - licenses
license_id | account_id | product_id | license_code
1          | 1          | 1          |
2          | 1          | 2          |
3          | 0          | 1          | abc123
```

I know `account_email`, `product_id` and `license_code` (this one can be empty) variables, and need to check if client has license for selected product (searching by `account_email` or `license_code`).

The problem is that `account_id` sometimes can be 0 (in other words, client has license, but client's profile is not stored in the accounts table).

Trying to use this one, but it returns wrong (duplicated) results:

```
SELECT * FROM licenses 
INNER JOIN products ON licenses.product_id=products.product_id AND products.product_id='X' 
INNER JOIN accounts ON licenses.account_id=accounts.account_id AND accounts.account_email='XYZ' OR licenses.license_code='ZZZ'
```

The question: how do I rewrite query, so I can find a record by `account_email` or `license_code` field? Put simply, if `account_id` is not 0 (profile exists), I should see data from 3 tables (accounts, products, licenses). If `account_id` is 0, I should see data from 2 tables (values from accounts table should be displayed as empty/null).

Needless to say, `account_email` and `license_code` fields are unique.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some more code modification and testing, here's the code which works perfectly. It's a modified Gordon Linoff's code (original code didn't work when only license_code was known, and email address wasn't known). So most of credits go to Gordon Linoff for his efforts.

```
SELECT *
FROM licenses l JOIN
     products p
     ON l.product_id = p.product_id LEFT JOIN
     accounts a
     ON l.account_id = a.account_id
WHERE p.product_id = 'X' AND
      (a.account_email='XYZ' OR l.license_code = 'ZZZ')
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to adjust the parentheses.  However, I would use a separate `WHERE` clause:

```
SELECT *
FROM licenses l INNER JOIN
     products p
     ON l.product_id = p.product_id INNER JOIN
     accounts a
     ON l.account_id = a.account_id
WHERE p.product_id = 'X' AND
      (a.account_email='XYZ' OR l.license_code = 'ZZZ')
```

You can keep the filters in the `ON` clauses -- there is nothing wrong with that.  I just prefer to separate join conditions from filtering conditions.  The important part are the parentheses, so the `ON` clause is not interpreted as:

```
ON (l.account_id = a.account_id AND a.account_email = 'XYZ') OR
  licenses.license_code = 'ZZZ'
```

This is the interpretation without parens.

Comment: need to remove 'AND' from before 2nd join :)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. It displayed multiple SQL errors, so I modified it a bit by removing 'AND' before 2nd join and removing 'AND' before the last 'WHERE'. Hope it's still OK?

Comment: Unfortunately, the code doesn't work. It works fine when account_email exists in database, but when account_email doesn't exist in database (so record needs to be found by license_code), 0 results are displayed.